# direct ssh connection when default proxy is configured in ~/.ssh/config

Tags: openssh

Here's my ssh config:

```
Host *.*
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/connect-proxy    -S proxy.home.net:1080 %h %p
```

It sets a default proxy for domains containing dots. I want to change it to connect directly to hosts matching *.home.net . Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negated local domains with exlamation mark:

```
Host !*.home.net *.*
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/connect-proxy    -S proxy.home.net:1080 %h %p
```

This works with version 6.3p1, but not 5.3p1.

Upd: Ultimate solution for old and new ssh

```
# for old ssh where negations don't work
Host !*.home.net *.home.net
    ProxyCommand ~/.ssh/netcat.sh %h %p

Host !*.home.net *.*
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/connect-proxy    -S proxy.home.net:1080 %h %p
```

I don't have nc.exe in my msysgit.

`~/.ssh/netcat.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' HUP # because ssh HUPs us after closing our stdin
exec 4<>"/dev/tcp/$1/$2" || exit 1
/bin/cat <&4 &
exec 1>&-
/bin/cat >&4 <&0
exec 0<&-
/bin/sleep 10
# sometime EOF never comes so kill the other cat
kill $!
```